# JavaScript/Prototype.js: Delete property from JSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```
var myJsonObj = {"employees":[{"name":"John", "lastName":"Doe", "age": 55},{"name":"Jane", "lastName":"Doe", "age":69}]};
```

How can I delete myJsonObj.eployees[1] ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Note: There is no such thing as a JSON object, JSON is a data interchange format. That's just a regular object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
delete myJsonObj.employees[1];
```

However, this will keep the index of all the other elements. If you want to re-order the index, too, you could use this:

```
// store current employee #0
var tmp = myJsonObj.employees.shift();
// remove old employee #1
myJsonObj.employees.shift();
// re-add employee #0 to the start of the array
myJsonObj.employees.unshift(tmp);
```

Or you use simply Darin Dimitrov's splice solution (see his answer below).

Answer (score 2):

```
myJsonObj.employees.splice(1, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/delete_Operator):

```
delete myJsonObj.employees[1]
```

or set it to `null`

```
myJsonObj.employees[1] = null;
```

Neither will affect the indices of any elements following the element deleted from an array.